# How to set queue name using laravel-excel implicit queued imports

Tags: laravel, import, queue, laravel-excel

I used [Implicit queued imports](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/queued.html#implicit-queued-imports) like below:

```
Excel::import(new UsersImport, 'users.xlsx');
```

but by default it used `default` as queue name. Here is the log

```
INFO  Processing jobs from the [default] queue.
2022-09-17 10:43:47 Maatwebsite\Excel\Jobs\ReadChunk
```

I want to change the queue name, so how to change the queue name?

In the documentation, only shows like below:

```
(new UsersImport)->queue('users.xlsx')->allOnQueue('imports');
```

But I need to use `Excel::import` or implicit method.

Comment: You can try using the `->onQueue` and `onConnection` methods in the constructor of `UsersImport` as described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#dispatching-to-a-particular-queue)

Answer (score 0):

I suggested you use Queueing closures

```
dispatch(function () {
    Excel::import(new UsersImport, 'users.xlsx');
})->onQueue("anything");
```